# Нужно объяснение части кода

Tags: c++

Можете объяснить некоторые части этого кода, а именно, что в структуре `func` значит строчка:

> func(int& i_) :i(i_) {}

а также, как работает в данном коде перегрузка оператора():

> void operator()()

Вот код:

```
#include <thread>

void do_something(int& i)
{
    ++i;
}

struct func
{
    
    int& i;

    func(int& i_) :i(i_) {}
    
    void operator()()
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j)
        {
            do_something(i);
        }
    }
    
};


void oops()
{
    int some_local_state = 0;
    func my_func(some_local_state);
    std::thread my_thread(my_func);
    my_thread.detach();
}

int main()
{
    oops();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Конструктор с аргументом `i_`, инициализирующий член `int&i` этим аргументом. Оператор просто миллион раз вызывает в цикле `do_something(i)`, это очевидно. Наверное, вы хотите узнать, не что он делает, а как применяется? просто внутри потока идет вызов `my_func()`, который и вызывает этот оператор...